# SharePoint 2013 - Display a Disclaimer or Terms of Service when creating MySite

Tags: 2013, my-site

We need to Display some Kind of disclaimer / Terms of usage when a user initially creates his mysite. Best solution would be to Display a Website with a "Yes" / "No" choice... Clicking "Yes" would continue to create the users mysite - "No" would cancel the process.

is there any way to do this?

Thanks in Avance!